# Open galleria in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, galleria

Hi have just started using galleria plugin and i would like to open it in modal like on thier site.
https://galleria.io/downloads/classic/
Mayby sb have aready done this before and is able to send me code

Comment: `like on thier site` where? And which modal are you using?

Comment: If you click "preview this theme" button it opens modal with gallery.

Comment: My guess is that the modal is not part of the plugin but [bootstrap modal](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/). So just try to use it. If it's not working maybe you should call the [`Galleria.run('.galleria');`](http://docs.galleria.io/article/15-beginners-guide#load-a-theme) after the modal is shown.